# Show/Hide div with Dropdown Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Relatively new to JS, need some help in getting a div to hide/show properly based on a dropdown choice.

If dropdown='no', div should be hidden. If dropdown='yes', div should show. I got the JS to work correctly at first, but once the form saves and I reopen it, the div disappears. I believe I've written the JS wrong by telling the div to show only on change. But I'm too new to know - help!

```js
$('.analysisPub').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value === "Yes") {
    $("#analysis").show();
  } else {
    $("#analysis").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.analysis {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Does this publication include analysis in any form?</td>

    <td class="analysisPub" id="analysisPub" name="analysisPub">
      <select>
        <option value>Yes</option>
        <option value>No</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="analysis" class="analysis">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Test Name</td>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can trigger the change logic on load - at this at the end of your handler: `}).change()`

Comment: To do this you need to save the show/hide of the `div` between the postbacks. Save it in a **Server Side** hidden field and use the hidden field value after the page load.

Comment: Ha - I'm too new to even know which part is the handler. Where exactly do I add }).change()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two main mistakes in your code. They are as follows -

```
1st - you were targetting the <td> rather than the <select>

2nd - your dropdown options were not having values
```

I've fixed them now. It works as u mentioned in the description.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropdownAnalysis').on('change', function() {
      if (this.value == 'Yes')
      {
        $("#analysis").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#analysis").hide();
      }
    });
});
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Does this publication include analysis in any form?</td>
    <td class="analysisPub" id="analysisPub" name="analysisPub">
     <select id="dropdownAnalysis">
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="analysis" class="analysis">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Test Name</td>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```